# Multiple Linear Regression Predictions with Macroeconomic Indicators

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, vector-autoregression, granger-causality, macroeconomics

We are given some commodity (steel, copper etc.) price predictions made by the following steps:

1. Finding the correlations between the commodity price data and macroeconomic indicators
2. Selecting a set of the indicators that are highly correlated with the commodity price data
3. Using the selected indicators as explanatory variables and the commodity price as
   dependent variable then applying multiple linear regressions.

My concern is that if an interdependency exists between the dependent and independent variables (if the commodity price affect some of the indicators), then can we trust multiple linear regression predictions, knowing a VAR model seems a better choice?

What would be the best way to determine if the commodity price affects any of the selected indicators, thinking a Granger Causality test?

On the other hand, if the commodity price does not affect any of the indicators (the explanatory variables), then the multiple linear regression forecasts sound fine but then another question arises: Since the correlation analysis looks at the linear relationships between the independent and dependent variables, and the indicators are selected according to the correlations, the macroeconomic indicators which have non-linear relationship with the commodity series won’t be selected.  Can the forecast results still capture the commodity trend sufficiently?

Please advise, many thanks.

Comment: A VAR does sound more appropriate in this situation. I'm not an expert in this, but I would have qualms about simple causality testing, since the data are frequently either highly aggregated (e.g., quarterly), or not very useful on less aggregate level (we do get prices on hourly level, but hourly unemployment is a bit dubious), so we don't have a lot of data for our causality tests, plus there are all kinds of other influences, from tariffs to wars and pandemics. Also, we need to forecast the predictors themselves...

Comment: Keep in mind that any linear regression will likely suffer from autocorrelation - which is a violation of Ordinary Least Squares whereby correlation exists across the residuals over time. For instance, you might find a correlation between copper prices and GDP for instance, but this is likely to be due to time effects rather than a true correlation. As mentioned, VAR is a good solution for this type of problem. That said, you could also use cointegration methods to see if any correlations are meaningful, or cross-correlation to see if lags of one variable might be useful in predicting another.